# Bind input to only one text input in angular

Tags: javascript, angular

There is a scenario where I use ngfor and adding the text box for each iteration. When I type anything in the text box it binds to every text box but I want to give input to that text box only which I click to enter a value.

```
<div class="comment" *ngFor="let comment of blog.comments"> 
  <p>posts...</p>
  <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="newComment.content" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
</div>
```

Comment: can you share your code?

Comment: Please share a *reprex* https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: <div class="comment" *ngFor="let comment of blog.comments">
<p>posts...</p>
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="newComment.content" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
</div>

@HUSSAIN, suppose it iterates 4 times, and then when I enter anything in any of the text boxes, it is written in all remaining 3.

Answer (score 0):

You are referring same `ngModel` to every text box.

- You need to have a array of `newComment` Objects.

> ```
> <div class="comment" *ngFor="let comment of blog.comments;let i = index"> 
>   <p>posts...</p>
>   <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="newComment[i].content" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
> </div>
> ```

Answer (score -1):

This should be like this: event -> target-> value will give you current input value

Html:

```
<input (keyup)="onKey($event)">
```

Component TS

```
onKey(event: any) {
    console.log(event.target.value)
  }
```